# Markov Chains and Return Times

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_{n≥0}$ be a Markov chain with transition kernel $p$ on a countable state space $S$, starting at $x∈S$

$T^{(1)}=\inf\{n≥1:X_n=x\} \quad \quad$ first return time to $x$

$T^{(2)}=\inf\{n>T^{(1)}:X_n=x\} \quad \quad$ second return time to $x$

Can we prove $$T^{(2)}=\infty \quad \text{a.s.}  \Longrightarrow  T^{(1)}=\infty \quad \text{a.s.}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If the chain starts at $x$, the strong Markov property at time $T^{(1)}$ indicates that $T^{(2)}=T^{(1)}+R$, where $R$ is independent of $T^{(1)}$ and with the same distribution. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: I think so, if that equality holds then suppose $P_x(T^{1}<∞)>0$ then $P_x(R<∞)=P_x(T^{1}<∞)>0$ and therefore $P_x(T^{2}<∞)>0$ Does this make any sense?

Comment: Absolutely, especially if you note that $[T^2\lt\infty]=[T^1\lt\infty]\cap[R\lt\infty]$.

Comment: Fine, thanks. But to be honest I don't see how does that equality follow from the strong Markov property. The only thing I can deduce from SMP is this $$P_x[T^{(2)}<∞]=P_x[T^{(2)}<∞]*P_x[T^{(1)}<∞]$$

Comment: SMP does not give what you say, but rather that $P(T^2\lt\infty\mid T^1,T^1\lt\infty)=P(R\lt\infty\mid T^1,T^1\lt\infty)=P(R\lt\infty)=P(T^1\lt\infty)$.